# Spring: How to implement multiple messgeSource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have 2 message sources, from database and many properties files

```
application_en_US.properties
application_vi_VN.properties
application_ja_JP.properties
application.properties
```

I try

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="com.example.InitializableMessageSource">
    <property name="messageProvider">
        <list>
            <bean id="jdbcMessageProvider" class="com.example.common.ultils.JdbcMessageProvider">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            </bean>
            <bean id="messageSource2"
                class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
                <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
                <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
            </bean>         
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have

```
package com.example;
public class InitializableMessageSource extends AbstractMessageSource implements InitializingBean {

}
```

but error (error convention). Please help me fix it.

Comment: Why invent your own? The `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` accepts a `parent` just set the `JdbcMessageProvider` as the parent. Or if the JDBC one is leading do it the other way around.

Comment: It's leagacy system.

Comment: So what has that to do with the proposed solution... A MessageSource has a parent/child relation ship... Just change the configuration, that has nothing to do with the fact if it is a legacy system or not.